# How to create reusable custom components in android

Tags: android

I want to create my own component like Dialog that can be used in any android application.

**what i have?**

*1. Some java classes
2. A layout(.xml)
3. Color resource*

I want to make a **jar** like Google have that can be used in another application.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes you can make it a library project and reference the same in another.http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: i have tried for library project but when i used this in another application it was unable to find my java classes.

Comment: you can refer the docs.